# JButton in JTable doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I'm trying to put a `JButton` in a `JTable`. It doesn't show. I did a lot of trying by what I found in the web, but nothing was working.

This is my code:

```
public  class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    JButton button;     
    boolean enabled = true; 

    public ButtonRenderer() 
    {     
        button = new JButton();     
    }



      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                              boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {


            if (table.getValueAt(row, column) == "clicked") {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            } else {

                button.setEnabled(true);
            }

            return button;
            }
      public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) 
        {     
            this.enabled = enabled;     
        }     
        }     

        class ButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements   
        TableCellEditor,ActionListener 
        {     
        JButton button;    
        private JTable cwwObjTblMainTable = null;
        boolean enabled = true;     
        int clickCountToStart = 1;     

        public ButtonEditor() 
        {     
            button = new JButton();     
            button.addActionListener(this);     
        }   

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,     
                Object value,     
                boolean isSelected,     
                int row, int column) {     

            cwwObjTblMainTable=table;
            button.setText("Voir");     
            button.setEnabled(enabled);     
            return button;     
        }     

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {     
            this.enabled = enabled;     
        }     

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {     
            return button.getText();     
        }     

        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {     
            if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {     
                return ((MouseEvent)anEvent).getClickCount() >= clickCountToStart;     
            }     
            return true;     
        }     

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {  
            enabled=false;
            button.setEnabled(false);
            //Business logic execution 
            System.out.println("Clicked");

        }
    }
```

**And the calling on the view:**

```
 tableau.setDefaultRenderer(JButton.class, new ButtonRenderer());
 tableau.getColumn("Voir l'évenement").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor());
```

Answer (score 1):

How you have tried to use `setDefaultRenderer()` in below line is incorrect. First parameter of this method must be the "data type" of the column which intends to use this renderer; Not the type of the renderer.

```
tableau.setDefaultRenderer(JButton.class, new ButtonRenderer());
```

Below program demonstrates how you can add a `JButton` to a `JTable`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class ButtonInTable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"aa", "aaa", ""},
            {"bb", "bbb", ""},
            {"cc", "ccc", ""},
            {"dd", "ddd", ""},
            {"ee", "eee", ""}},
        new Object[] {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});

    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.getColumn("Column 3").setCellRenderer(new RendererAndEditor());
    table.getColumn("Column 3").setCellEditor(new RendererAndEditor());

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class RendererAndEditor implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {

  private JButton button;

  RendererAndEditor() {
    button = new JButton("Button");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button clicked");
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                                 boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    return button;
  }

  @Override
  public java.awt.Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row,
                                                        int column) {
    return button;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void cancelCellEditing() { }

  @Override
  public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) { }

  @Override
  public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) { }
}
```